# Is the a specific webkit feature I can detect to check if a user is using a webkit browser

Tags: webkit, feature-detection

I've used the code below if I need to detect Firefox:

```
var firefox = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
```

I'm curious if there is something similar to detect webkit browsers without checking the user agent string. Like checking a specific feature only webkit browsers have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the console in Chrome and type `window.webkit` - the autocompletion will show you a stack of properties that should be Webkit specific (e.g. `webkitRequestAnimationFrame`, `webkitAudioContext`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the best practise is to use

`window.webkitConvertPointFromNodeToPage`

`window.WebKitCSSMatrix`

`window.WebKitPoint`

These are one of the oldest properties, which support was firstly introduced in safari 4.0
Chrome supports this since first version, opera has owned such property right after it's engine migration.

UPD:
@hexalys found a better solution:

```
'WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style
```

this one is supported even in safari 3.0