# Hide webkit pseudo using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, webkit

I am trying to hide the calendar icon that appears next to a input of type date. I have no problem hiding it using css.

```
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none; }
```

However I only want to hide it in certain circumstances so need to hide with jquery or javascript but what ever I try it will not hide.

```
$("::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator").css("display", "none");
```

Primarily I am only concerned with chrome.

How do I hide this webkit element using jquery?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54749402/8620333

Answer (score 0):

[Detect Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756811), then add a class:

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('AppleWebKit') != -1) {
  //Add any other conditions here
  $('input[type=date]').addClass('webkitDate');
}
```

```css
.webkitDate::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" />
```