# check if browser support an html attribute value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use `<input type="week">` and `<input type="month">`.

My problem is that those `type` values are currently supported only by webkit browsers, and others fall back to `type=text"`. I need them to fall back to `type="date"`.

**Is there a javascript method to check if an attribute value is supported by the browser?**

Comment: "To detect whether the browser supports <input type="week">, we create a new <input> element, try setting its type to week, then immediately check what its type is set to. Non-supporting browsers will return text, because the week type falls back to type text." ([<input type="week"> examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/week#examples))

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625321/detect-webkit-browser-in-javascript#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20know%20if,test(navigator.