# Making the browser load a js file and run scripts if the browser is webkit only (Chrome, Safari)

Tags: html, svg, webkit

As web developers, we are all used to have code such as the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><script src="/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```

Where you have conditional statements based on if the client is an older IE browser.

Well, this time I'm working with stacked svg and surprisingly, the browser needing a fix is webkit based browsers. I could make a blanket load for all browsers, but I wonder if I could have a similar conditional loading condition for webkit. I hope I don't have to use js for this.

Comment: 1) You would have to use JS. 2) Please never do this. What’s the bug and what’s the fix?

Comment: Webkit browsers wouldn't display stacked svg correctly and need the fixsvgstack.js script. If I have to use js, I might as well use a blanket load for all browsers. For more information, see: http://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/svg-stacking/

Comment: Please refer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625876/how-to-detect-chrome-and-safari-browser-webkit>

Comment: @BringMeAnother: Support for them was intentionally dropped: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128055#c6

Comment: Not sure what your objection is against using JS for loading a piece of JS.

Comment: Yeah, to think of it, I should just use JS. I was expecting something similar to the IE comments. Besides, after some soul searching, I've decided not use svg stack after all and wait for Chrome to support svg fragments. Meanwhile I think I'll use inline svg by having php include the file.