# Safari canPlayType() marks .ogg as "probably" & HTML5 <audio><source> does not play

Tags: javascript, html, safari, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I want to create a html5 audioplayer for my band's website.

The audiofiles are stored in the database as *mp3*, *ogg* and *wav* files to support all major browsers on their current versions.

First, all audiofileversions for one audiofile are loaded into the html:

```
<audio class="song-preview" preload="none">
    <source type="audio/ogg" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/OGG"></source>
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/MP3"></source>
    <source type="audio/wav" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/WAV"></source>
</audio>
```

**Method I:**
Javascript checks with `audio.canPlayType(type)` for browser support and removes all unsupported `<source>` elements and adds a `"probably"` source to the `<audio>`'s `src` attribute.

**[Example I:](http://jsbin.com/filoxudewu/2/edit?html,js,output)** *(not working on my iphone)*.

**Problem I:**
Nested `<source>` elements in an `<audio>` element doesn't work well. (Altough Safari normally plays a given mp3 from an `<audio>`'s `src`, it does not if it is in the `<source>`'s `src`. Having big wav files in the sources prevents mobile devices from playing the audio, too.)

**Method II:**
Javascript checks with `audio.canPlayType(type)` for browser support and adds the first "probably"-supported `<source>`'s `src` to the `<audio>`'s `src` attribute. After that all `<source>` elements are removes.

**[Example II:](http://jsbin.com/lonenileke/1/edit?html,js,console,output)** *(I am no JS expert but jsbin seems not to handle canPlayType() properly)*.

**Problem II:**
Safari classifys my ogg-files as `"probably"` and then does not play them.

- Why is the audio from `<source>` elements not playing?
- Any ideas on how to better check for audiotype browsersupport?
- Is having the same src in the `<audio>` element and the `<source>` child normally working?

Comment: this might help a bit: http://caniuse.com/#search=audio

Comment: welcome to the weird world of html5 audio. this might help too.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: should I write custom javascript for safari browsers, to exclude the OGG files? Or does this method not cover all major browsers?

Comment: although a multi-<source> solution would give more flexibility

Comment: Is your ogg wrapping a vorbis or an opus codec?

Comment: The used Codec is Vorbis audio (vorb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working "solution" so far:

Detect safari on desktops, if true, remove all ogg sources.

```
var isSafari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

if (isSafari) {
    $(this).children("source[type!='audio/mpeg']").remove();
}
```

[code above found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625876/how-to-detect-chrome-and-safari-browser-webkit)

This solution is not recommended, since it depends on the send user-agent, which can be faked, etc.

Combined with the following code, the `probably` playable source file is merged into the `src` attribute of the audio element. This lets safari play your html audio properly:

```
$(this).children("source").each(function(){
    switch ($audio_preview[0].canPlayType($(this).attr("type"))) {
        case "":
            $(this).remove();
            break;
        case "maybe":
            $audio_preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
            break;
        case "probably":
            $audio_preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
            $audio_preview.children("source").remove();
            break;
        default:
            $audio_preview.attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the file extensions?
I have seen people having succes by keeping the minetype .ogg,
but changing the extensions to .oga for audio and .ogv for video.

```
<audio class="song-preview" preload="none" id="NameOfSong">
    <source type="audio/ogg" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/OGa"></source>
    <source type="audio/mpeg" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/MP3"></source>
    <source type="audio/wav" src="/preview/trees/trees/OG/DT/WAV"></source>
</audio>
```